# Помогите найти решение ошибки Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php

[image: скриншот кода в котором есть ошибка]

Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку [image: вот еще кусок кода]

Comment: Покажите код где определяется $result

Comment: // Запрос к БД
        $result = $db->query('SELECT id, name FROM category WHERE status = "1" ORDER BY sort_order, name ASC');

Answer (score 0):

Во первых у вас скорее всего проблема в коде запроса, во вторых зачем так усложнять цикл? в вашем случае можно цикл упростить в разы..

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT id, name FROM category WHERE status = "1" ORDER BY sort_order, name ASC');
if(!$result) echo $db->error;
$categoryList = array();
While($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  $categoryList[]=$row;
```

Comment: Вы так уверенно пишете ответ, а что тут используется-то, знаете - PDO, mysqli или `$db` вообще какой-то абстрактный интерфейс?

Comment: @u_mulder Уверено пишу что? судя по синтаксису и уровню вопроса тянет только на mysql(i)